# How to analyze/compare all rows pairwise combination in pandas and keep count?

Tags: pandas, loops, count, iteration, python-itertools

My df `df.shape` `(15,4)` with `df.head()`

```
      C1     C2    C3   C4
A1  82.0  78.00  1100  3.0
A2  19.0  99.00  9520  3.0
A3  25.0  42.00  1700  7.0
A4  93.0  37.00  1700  7.0
A5   9.2   0.44   510  7.0
```

I want to pairwise comparison of all rows in df with each other. Comparison between (A1,A2); (A1,A3); (A1,A4); (A1,A4); (A2,A3); (A2,A4); (A2,A5); (A3,A4).. and so on with their respective columns.

Comparison criteria: `if(A1,C1 > A2,C1)--> then keep count of A1 as winner and A2 as loser`

```
elif(A1,C1 < A2,C1)--> vice versa A2 has a winner count, A1 gets loser count
elif(A1,C1 == A2,C1)--> Add 0.5 to the count of both A1 and A2 since it is a draw./ or can keep count in a new Draw count column.
```

Store all these counts of pairwise row comparison in a new df.

For the given `df.head()` The output should look something like this:

```
df_new.head()

     Wins  Loses  Draws  
A1     7    8       1 
A2     6    9       1 
A3     8    5       3 
A4     9    4       3 
A5     2    12      2
```

SO far, I've been able to generate a df with all possible combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations
fd = pd.DataFrame(index = combinations(df.index,2))
fd['Ccom'] =  list(combinations(df.C,2))
fd['Wcom'] =  list(combinations(df.W,2))
fd['Lcom'] =  list(combinations(df.L,2))
fd['Dcom'] =  list(combinations(df.D,2))

fd.head()
                    Ccom            Wcom             Lcom            Dcom
('A1', 'A2')    (82.0, 19.0)    (78.0, 99.0)    (1100.0, 9520.0)    (3.0, 3.0)
('A1', 'A3')    (82.0, 25.0)    (78.0, 42.0)    (1100.0, 1700.0)    (3.0, 7.0)
('A1', 'A4')    (82.0, 93.0)    (78.0, 37.0)    (1100.0, 1700.0)    (3.0, 7.0)
('A1', 'A5')    (82.0, 9.2)     (78.0, 0.44)    (1100.0, 510.0)     (3.0, 7.0)
('A2', 'A3')    (82.0, 52.0)    (78.0, 0.042)   (1100.0, 1100.0)    (3.0, 17.2)
```

(SOme change in values)..
How do I extract win counts from these all possible combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not very good solution, it works. I believe that there is more efficient way to handle this.

```
import pandas as pd

# note that this function will compare the row with itself
# thus producing one additional draw
def outcome(x,a):
    return (x<a,x==a,x>a)
 
# placeholder columns, C2 is unused
d = {'C1': [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0], 'C2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
# named index
ind = ['A'+str(x+1) for x in range(len(d['C1']))]
# construct dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=ind)


res = []
#iterate over
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # count wins, draws, defeats
    res.append((index, df['C1'].apply(lambda x: outcome(x,row['C1']))))

# parse results to obtain clean sums of outcomes
ind = [str(res[j][0]) for j in range(len(res))]
res = [[sum([y[i] for y in res[j][1]]) for i in range(3)] for j in range(len(res))]

# create temporary dataframe
tempDf = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['W','D','L'], index = ind)
# correct draw counts
tempDf['D']-=1

# merge dataframes
df = df.merge(tempDf, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

the output is

```
     C1  C2  W  D  L
A1  2.0   1  2  1  5
A2  1.0   2  0  1  7
A3  1.0   3  0  1  7
A4  4.0   4  5  0  3
A5  9.0   5  8  0  0
A6  5.0   6  6  1  1
A7  5.0   7  6  1  1
A8  3.0   8  4  0  4
A9  2.0   9  2  1  5
```